# How can I force the login screen to appear when user re-opens their web browser after auto-logged out time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

Good afternoon.

I have a situation with a SSL web application written in C# in that if I log in and navigate to a secure page, close my browser and open it again after the login has expired, the content that was shown when closing the browser still appears.

In other words, if the login cookie expires after 30 minutes, and I close the browser and re-open it (restoring my tabs) after 30 minutes, the page that I was viewing still appears and not the expected login page.

If I click on a link after re-opening the browser that is supposed to take me to another secure location, I am redirected to the login page, but I'd like to prevent the previous page content from being shown again since it could contain sensitive data.

The page content is set to expire after 30 minutes and the user login cookie is set to expire after 30 minutes as well. (See images below)

I'm not sure how to force the login screen to appear when re-opening a browser. Thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Set Common HTTP Response Headers Dialog]
[image: Edit Forms Authentication Settings Dialog]

EDIT: Relevant content of web.config if it will help.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>

    [REMOVED]

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms path="/" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name="[REMOVED]" requireSSL="true" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

    [REMOVED]

    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:30:00" />
    </staticContent>

    [REMOVED]

  </system.webServer>

  [REMOVED]

</configuration>
```

OnLoad Method from the Site.Master page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* 
     * See if the user has read the service agreement, if not, send the user to the service agreement page.
     * Do NOT process this if it is being called from the service agreement page!
     * If you do, we will end up with an infinite loop and infinite loops are bad mmmkay?
     */
    if (!Profile.IsAnonymous && !Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
    {
        if (!Profile.ServiceAgreementStatusOkay())
        {
            if (Page.Request.RawUrl != @"/Account/KB/SA/")
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Account/KB/SA/");
            }
        }
    }

    // only check messages if the user isn't anonymous
    if (!Profile.IsAnonymous)
    {
        int UnreadMessageCount = 0;
        SqlDataSourceMessageCount.SelectParameters["UserId"].DefaultValue = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        SqlDataSourceMessageList.SelectParameters["UserId"].DefaultValue = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();

        Repeater MessageListRepeater = ((Repeater)LoginViewUserMenu.FindControl("RepeaterMessages"));

        SqlDataReader CountReader = null;
        DataView MessageListDataView = new DataView();

        try
        {
            CountReader = (SqlDataReader)SqlDataSourceMessageCount.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            if (CountReader.HasRows)
            {
                CountReader.Read();

                UnreadMessageCount = CountReader.SafeGetInt32(0);

                if (UnreadMessageCount != 0)
                {
                    ((Literal)LoginViewUserMenu.FindControl("LiteralMessageCount")).Text = UnreadMessageCount.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Literal)LoginViewUserMenu.FindControl("LiteralMessageCount")).Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            SqlDataSourceMessageList.FilterParameters.Clear();
            SqlDataSourceMessageList.FilterExpression = string.Empty;
            SqlDataSourceMessageList.FilterParameters.Add("IsRead", "false");
            SqlDataSourceMessageList.FilterExpression = "IsRead = {0}";

            MessageListDataView = (DataView)SqlDataSourceMessageList.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            MessageListRepeater.DataSource = MessageListDataView;
            MessageListRepeater.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorNotifier Err = new ErrorNotifier();
            Err.Notify(ex, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (CountReader != null)
            {
                if (!CountReader.IsClosed)
                {
                    CountReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // set the value of the bug report path.
    TextBoxPath.Text = Page.Request.RawUrl;

    // set footer stuff.
    AppCopyrightDate.Text = AppAttributes.GetCopyrightString();
    LiteralVersionNumber.Text = AppAttributes.AppVersion.ToString();

    // set theme info.
    ThemeManager TM = new ThemeManager();

    if (Request["ThemePreview"] == null)
    {
        LiteralTheme.Text = TM.GetThemeLink(Profile.UX.Theme);
    }
    else
    {
        LiteralTheme.Text = TM.GetThemeLink(Request["ThemePreview"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you confirm that login cookie is expired? Could you show the web.config *(hide sensitive information)*?

Comment: Sure, just a minute and I'll update the question with the content of the web.config file. but the section that sets the cookie to expire is here:

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms path="/" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".COOKIENAME" requireSSL="true" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

Comment: Also, if the cookie wasn't expired, when I click on a link on the page that re-opens, it wouldn't take me to the login page, it would just show that content. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Could you comment out `staticContent` tag in the mean time?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: If we have too many variables, we won't know what causes the issue. Besides, we don't normally use `staticContent` for site-wide.

Comment: OK I commented out the <staticContent> section and the problem still remains. Any other ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Could you show the OnLoad code? As well as the fields in your cookie? All you should have to do ids check for the cookie on load and if its expired redirect to the login page.

Comment: True, but the onload code won't run if the browser just shows the page from cache. I can't control the browser sending the request. But I know many sites (including this one) when I re-open my browser and my session is expired, I have to log in again. I'll add my OnLoad code though to the question.